# QuickFIX C++: How to return to main() after reconnect?

Tags: c++, quickfix

So my question is exactly as it is in the title - how do I return to main() of the program after reconnect of the FIX Initiator? Why do I ask this question? Because in my main() of the program, I constantly read the data from the database, but after logoff-reconnect - my program doesn't return to main(), it doesn't read the data from database anymore. So my question is - what should I do in my application so after reconnect I can return to my main() of the program and continue execution? What should I change in my FIX settings? If you require additional information, or you need to see my settings or something else - please post. Thank you very much in advance guys!

Comment: Sounds like your program design needs your main() not to read data from the DB but call a sub function readData() to do that, and then when there's a reconnect use the QuickFIX onLogon() to call that sub function readData()

Comment: Thank you for your answer rupweb. But you see, in my main() I am not only reading the database, but also check for order status, for example, and many other stuff. Should I migrate all that stuff to the class?

Comment: Yes, can I suggest designing your code according to the UNIX philosophy applied to coding so each class does 1 thing and does it well, and each class can talk to every other class. Anyway, so you have a DB class that handles only DB interactions. Your main class calls that one, and further, then if you reconnect in your QF layer, then QF calls that class as well, etc...